# Ugly Widgets - Android

Tags: android, layout, widget

I'm new to Android programming, and i'm building a small test program.

My problem is that in the graphical layout of the .xml files the widgets(Spinners,Buttons...) looks nice and round, but when I put my program into my phone(Nexus S, if that matters) or in the emolator, they come out with rounded edges,making the whole program look really ugly.

Is theres something i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please make some screenshots of what exactly you mean? It is very hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: I've uploaded an image - 
http://img109.imageshack.us/i/differenced.jpg/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have set the build target to 2.2 or earlier and Nexus S is running 2.3, which has redesigned UI elements. If you set build target to 2.3 it sould show the same (not rounded) buttons and other elements in the Eclipse XML viewer as they are in the Nexus S.

Comment: you can fix this by grabbing up the resources you like from the github and replacing them in your project.  make your own theme with the nicer buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Nexus S doesn't use the default android theme.  Many of the standard UI items (radio buttons, buttons, check boxes etc) will have a different look than the UI builder will show.

Edit: wait...its showing up different in the emulator too??  my answer may not apply in that case, sorry :-\

Answer (score 0):

So the unrounded buttons are the new ones? Isn't that stupid? The are uglier.
And I set the build target to 1.6, and both the emulator and the nexus s are running 2.3,so that explains it.
Does anyone has a guide that explains how to change the UI items to nicer ones?

Comment: You can add the rounded elements to your drawable - download SDK 2.2 or earlier and grab them from [your sdk folder]/platforms/android-[SDK version lower than 9]/data/res. However I would let the elements to be as they are, because some ppl like the new design in 2.3.